# HTML: making a map through text inputs

Tags: html, maps, direction

i want to have a driver direction map on my website where 'start' and 'destination' locations are gotten from  two text input fields respectively and displayed on the map.Thanks  in Advance!!

Comment: Please provide us with some code which displays what you have tried so far. Stackoverflow is to solve problems, not to let other people write your code!

Comment: Well, you can use [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=pt-br), there they have a lot of examples, maybe one of them lead you to your solution

Comment: Please i tried this but it gives me  a static location but i want  users to input their locations in textbox then it appears on the map. Thanks for your reply though. I am really greatful. This is what i tried                                                                                            <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=place_id:ChIJibUym7U91A8RHoEP3GgCixo&destination=place_id:ChIJtXnv00o81A8RQdaU-qlrHGY&key=AIzaSyCANi9dpSWgm9k2aMYR2PkqGr92a5KVZ2U" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add comments yet, I don't know what is your programming language cause you didn't specify that, but if it was javascript then you can visit this website:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

So first of all you need a map in your website and you need to access the maps, in this case you'll need API, for example `google maps API`, and then you will start writing the code to make directories.

Your question is not clear enough btw, you have to specify exactly what do you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: no problem, but did it help you ?! if so please accept my answer @EliasuPamjanet